# How to override a link's href attribute in mod_menu?

Tags: overrides, menu-item

Better title might be 'How to set the menuItem object 'link' property?'

I've used menu overrides for a variety of purposes such as changing layout and styling etc but would now like to change the href of a menu item with a certain alias.

By default, the attributes are built like so:

```
$attributes = array();

if ($item->anchor_title)
{
    $attributes['title'] = $item->anchor_title;
}

if ($item->anchor_css)
{
    $attributes['class'] = $item->anchor_css;
}

if ($item->anchor_rel)
{
    $attributes['rel'] = $item->anchor_rel;
}
```

Ideally I'd like something like:

```
switch ($item->alias) {
  case 'specificAlias':
    $attributes['href'] = "www.desired_link.com";
    $linktype = $item->title;
    break;
  default:
    $linktype = $item->title;
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
$item['link'] = "www.theDesiredLink.com";
```

I will be working out the URL dynamically which is why I can't set it manually for the menu item.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use the 'flink' property in the $item object.

Full solution was as follows:

```
switch ($item->alias) {
  case 'a specific alias':
    $item->flink = "the desired URL";
    $linktype = $item->title;
    break;
  default:
    $linktype = $item->title;
}
```